# Website Homescreen icons not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, web, visualforce

I have a imbedded icons in my webpage for the home screen.

```
 <!-- iPhone 5 ICON -->
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.AppImages, 'icon_iphone5SNSB@3x-180.png')}" sizes="180x180" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
    <!-- iPhone 6 ICON -->
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.AppImages, 'icon_iphone6NSB@2x-120.png')}" sizes="120x120" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
```

I've tried it on the iOS simulator and it works for iPhone 5 iOS 7 but doesn't work for iPhone 5 iOS 8.  I'm not sure if it's iOS 8 or the version of safari but on the iOS 8 device it just shows the screen shot icon.

Are there new tags for iOS 8?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of SSL certificate. Your website wouldn't be having a vaild ssl certificate